# primefaces requiredMessage gets lost when p:autoComplete moved into custom component

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces in a pretty standard Java web app (jsf-2) and am having an issue with my required message displaying when I move a p:autoComplete component into it's own custom component..

first, the p:autoComplete when it's on the page itself - this is working fine (simplified):

```
<h:panelGrid  id="newRoleAdminGrid" >

            <p:autoComplete id="newRoleAdminPerson"
                            style="position: relative; padding-right:5px"
                            value="#{roleList.newRoleAdminPerson}"
                            var="personVar" 
                            itemValue="#{personVar}" 
                            itemLabel="#{personVar.fullFamiliarName}"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            completeMethod="#{personAutoComplete.byGeneralCriteria}"
                            converter="PersonConverter"
                            minQueryLength="3"
                            maxResults="50" 
                            scrollHeight="400"
                            size="50"
                            required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="admin name is requiredd"
                            title="enter users first name, last name or login" >
            </p:autoComplete> 

            <h:message for="newRoleAdminPerson" class="redError"/>

            <p:commandButton value="add" ajax="true" 
                             update="roleAdminTable,newRoleAdminGrid"
                             id="addRoleAdminBtn"
                             actionListener="#{roleList.newRoleAdmin}"
                             style="margin:5px;"
                             icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

see that h:message above? that works perfect and displays when the value is blank, or it doesnt pass the PersonConverter...

however I have this same component all over my app, so i created a custom component.

here's the component:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" type="String" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="person" type="com.foo.bar.model.Person" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="size" type="int" required="false" default="50" />
    <cc:attribute name="required" type="boolean" required="false" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="requiredMessage" type="String" required="false" default="required" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->

<cc:implementation>

    <p:autoComplete id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                    style="position: relative; padding-right:5px"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.person}"
                    var="personVar" 
                    itemValue="#{personVar}" 
                    itemLabel="#{personVar.fullFamiliarName}"
                    forceSelection="true"
                    completeMethod="#{personAutoComplete.byGeneralCriteria}"
                    converter="PersonConverter"
                    minQueryLength="3"
                    maxResults="50" 
                    scrollHeight="400"
                    size="#{cc.attrs.size}"
                    required="#{cc.attrs.required}" 
                    requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredMessage}"
                    title="enter users first name, last name or login" >
    </p:autoComplete>

    <h:message for="#{cc.attrs.id}" class="redError"/>

</cc:implementation>
```

and here's what code looks like now (that uses the custom component):

```
<h:panelGrid  id="newRoleAdminGrid" >

            <my:personLookup id="newRoleAdminPerson"  
                             person="#{roleList.newRoleAdminPerson}"
                             required="true" requiredMessage="#{propUtil.appShortName} Admin Name is required"/>

            <h:message for="newRoleAdminPerson" class="redError"/>

            <p:commandButton value="add" ajax="true" 
                             update="roleAdminTable,newRoleAdminGrid"
                             id="addRoleAdminBtn"
                             actionListener="#{roleList.newRoleAdmin}"
                             style="margin:5px;"
                             icon="ui-icon-plus"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
```

when i run it this way, the component works - if the user leaves it blank, or it doenst pass vaildation the primefaces border turns red, but the h:message never displays the actual error (requiredMessage or what is set in the PersonConverter)

i've tried quite a few different variations of this, such as setting the id only in the implementation or just in the my:personLookup, or both.

has anyone run across this before? am i doing or setting something incorrectly? thank you for you time!!

Comment: Have you tried using `p:message` instead?

Comment: @elias I sure have.. additionally i can't seem to get anything in **p:messages**, or **h:messages** either.

Comment: Why do you have `h:message` in composite component and also outside of it? Which `message` do you want? If you want to use `message` inside composite just assign `id="autocomplete"` to `autocomplete` and put `for="autocomplete"` in `message`. Composite component is naming container so you don't need to worry about id uniqueness.

Comment: thank you @partlov, i had tried this but other changes negated the solution and kept the message hidden initially. your comments put me back on the correct path, and i will post the final solution below for others that come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @partlov for the solution. here is my final code that displays the message correctly -

the component:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->

<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="person" type="com.foo.bar.model.Person" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="size" type="int" required="false" default="50" />
    <cc:attribute name="required" type="boolean" required="false" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="requiredMessage" type="String" required="false" default="required" />
</cc:interface>


<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->

<cc:implementation>

    <p:autoComplete id="personAutoComplete"
                    style="position: relative; padding-right:5px"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.person}"
                    var="personVar" 
                    itemValue="#{personVar}" 
                    itemLabel="#{personVar.fullFamiliarName}"
                    forceSelection="true"
                    completeMethod="#{personAutoComplete.byGeneralCriteria}"
                    converter="PersonConverter"
                    minQueryLength="3"
                    maxResults="50" 
                    scrollHeight="400"
                    size="#{cc.attrs.size}"
                    required="#{cc.attrs.required}" 
                    requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredMessage}"
                    title="enter users first name, last name or login" >
    </p:autoComplete>

    <h:message for="personAutoComplete" errorClass="redError" class="redError"/>

</cc:implementation>
```

calling in in my xhtml:

```
<my:personLookup id="newRoleAdminPerson"  
                     person="#{roleList.newRoleAdminPerson}"
                     required="true" requiredMessage="Admin Name is required"/>
```

Comment: note: keeping **h:message** outside of the component, and in the calling page may be invalid... would need more research.